# Bash - Arrange data according to primary key sequence without displaying primary key

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have one text file that stores criteria which is not in the sequence
**criteria.txt**

```
key2|criteria2|desc2|4
key1|criteria1|desc1|3    
key3|criteria3|desc3|4
```

I want to display the criteria assigned to the person from **criteria.txt** according to its first column **without displaying the **first column**** variable:

```
criteria1    desc1
criteria2    desc2
criteria3    desc3
```

I have tried two lines of code. First one is

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%s %-20s%s\n", $1, $2, $3} criteria2.txt | sort
```

This sorts the data by the key. However, this will print the key variable. So i tried the second line:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%-20s%s\n", $2, $3} criteria2.txt | sort
```

This display the criteria and description but it is sorted by the description instead of key. How do I display desc and the third column **without displaying the key variable**?

Edit:

I use this code and it works:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%s %-20s%s\n", $1, $2, $3} criteria2.txt | sort | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: Just append this to the first version of your awk pipeline: `| cut -d' ' -f2-`. Or, sort before calling awk: `sort criteria2.txt | awk -F'|' '{ printf "%-20s%s\n", $2, $3}'`

Comment: i use the first solution and it works! Thank you!!